# 'Type' (SCRATCH) Attribute details of API instances.attachDisk()

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to use `instances.attachDisk` API. In its description of request body fields, one of the fields is `type`. Below is the description of it:

type    enum
        Specifies the type of the disk, either **SCRATCH** or PERSISTENT. If not 
        specified, the default is PERSISTENT.

While adding disk I only see two types 'Standard persistent' and 'SDD persistent'.

So I would like to know below details of "SCRATCH" type:

1. What does "SCRATCH" means here?
2. How to add scratch disk?
3. Where is documentation of "SCRATCH" disks? I have gone through storage related docs but didn't found any specific note regarding "SCRATCH" disks.

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_space)

> Scratch space is space on the hard disk drive that is dedicated for only temporary storage. It cannot be used to permanently back up files. Scratch disks can be set to erase all data at regular intervals so that the disk space is left free for future use.

Define disk type as Scratch in your API call.

**Example**

```
{
  "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
  "mode": "READ_WRITE",
  "deviceName": "local-ssd-0",
  "type": "SCRATCH",
  "autoDelete": false,
  "interface": "SCSI",

}
```

There's no full documentation dedicated for `scratch disk`, however the following document on [#localssds](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds) will help.

On a side note, if you did not specify `disks[].type` the default which is  **PERSISTENT** will be used. See the [Instance resource page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances) for a JSON API representations of all available resources.

You may also use the [Google API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/attachDisk) to call this method on live data to see the API request and response.

**How to list Scratch disk after creation:**

`df -h` command will not show your scratch disk, this is because they must format and mount the device before you can use it.

Try: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/`

See how to [format and mount SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#formatandmount).

Note: Local SSDs (Scratch disk) are located on the physical machine where your virtual machine instance is running, they can be created only during the instance creation process. Local SSDs cannot be used as boot devices.

Also see the Google Cloud platform Blog on "[The new Persistent Disk - faster, cheaper and more predictable for Google Compute Engine](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/12/the-new-persistent-disk-faster-cheaper-and-predictable-for-compute-engine.html)

Comment: Thanks for your information. Does it mean we cannot detach scratch disk from one instance and attach it to other instance in GCP? Need some clarification on it.

Comment: And does Local SSDs are scratch disks in GCP?

Comment: Hi Sunny,  Could you please reply on comments?

Comment: In GCP, storage space is much less expensive for a standard persistent disk. An SSD persistent disk is better for random IOPS or streaming throughput with low latency.  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/?hl=en_US&_ga=2.227770909.-1667003098.1530894364

Because SSD is available on all of Google primary instances, you can easily configure a much smaller instance type and still keep the power of local SSD and are efficient to be used as a scratch disk. 

So, Google recommend Local SSDs to be used as an efficient scratch disk. Hope this answers your question.